# Stackdriver Alert based on service status

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, stackdriver

Is it possible to setup an alert based on the status of a custom service. For example, stackdriver-agent service crashed at one point. When running 'service stackdriver-agent status" I receive an 'Active: inactive (dead)' response.

Is it possible to setup an alert based on the condition above? The stackdriver-agent service is just an example. In theory, I would like to setup this alert condition on any service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. In Stackdriver you can set up an alarm for any process in your machine. Selecting the option [Add Process Health Condition](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/#process-health) you can configure alarms to receive notifications if your process starts or stops. Bear in mind that you first have to set up the [Stackdriver Agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) in your machine and that this option is only available in [Stackdriver premium](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing).

Answer (score 0):

Thrahir's answer is a good one, though the UI has changed since then (click the right arrow next to "Metric" and "Uptime Check" to see other condition types; "Process Health" is the very last one).

If your service is a server, you might rather use an uptime check (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/) to monitor its state; that gives you a better analog to what the service's users will see than directly monitoring your processes does.

Aaron Sher, Stackdriver engineer